# Is there a workaround for CORS when using XMLHttpRequest with a local file?

Tags: html, cors, html5-filesystem, xmlhttprequest-level2

I'd like to use [Exif.js](https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js) to read JPEG EXIF tags from a local file. However, the javascript lib uses `XMLHttpRequest` to read JPG files as a `BinaryFile`:

```
function getImageData(oImg, fncCallback) 
{
    BinaryAjax(
        oImg.src,
        function(oHTTP) {
            var oEXIF = findEXIFinJPEG(oHTTP.binaryResponse);
            oImg.exifdata = oEXIF || {};
            if (fncCallback) fncCallback();
        }
    )
}
```

When I use  `<input type="file">` I get an HTML5 `File` object which I can read using a `FileReader` but I don't know how to convert this to a `BinaryFile`:

```
_initHTML5FileReader = function() {
  var chooseFile;
  chooseFile = document.getElementById("html5-get-file");
  chooseFile.onchange = function(e) {
    var file;
    file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
    var reader;
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(ev) {
      var dataUrl = ev.target.result;
      // How do I change this to a BinaryFile???
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    return false;
  };
};
```

But I also using AppGyver Steroids (PhoneGap) which serves my page from `http://localhost/index.html`, and when I try to use Exif.js, I get this CORS error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load    data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4X2cRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAOAA8BAgAKAAAAtgAAABABAgAI…N6gn14dm6BmJyMdYaMhX16hI+HgIWLj5aWkJOaiHF7hoV+dnBwc3Jzbm14hGlZcIaWlXFEU3OB. Received an invalid response. Origin 'http://localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Is there any way to configure XmlHttpRequest to serve a local File object without the CORS error?

Comment: Does the error message indicate which line of code is failing? Is it readAsDataURL, or something else?

Comment: no, the error is unrelated to FileReader.readAsDataURL(). The error is from XMLHttpRequest. 

I was trying to find a workaround using FileReader - some way to get a BinaryFile from the FileReader, but those APIs do not overlap. Is there another way?